# Can I tell Google that the current page has a different URL with a meta tag?

Tags: seo, url

I have the following scenario with items within different categories:

- catagory1 has the URL `example.com/category1`
- category2 has the URL `example.com/category2`
- [...]
- all `example.com/all` to show posts of all categories

Every item get's the following permalink (category name/item slug):

`example.com/category1/item-slug`

To not lose context when I come from the `all` category the permalinks are 
`example.com/all/item-slug`

Is it possible to tell google with a meta tag or something like that that the real URL for this page is `example.com/category1/item-slug`, so that it indexes the better URL and not the one with `all`. I'm also worried about duplicate content being introduced by this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have multiple pages of the same content, you're supposed to use the canonical tag.

On the page site.url/all/item-slug, you should have

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/category1/item-slug" />
```

Put the above code in your `<head>` tag and it will tell Google that you want the other URL to be indexed instead of the current page.

Comment: I updated the URL in the `href` to be fully qualified (with the `http://`).  It wouldn't have worked the way you had it without that.